# ASP.NET AWS Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda

After publishing the serverless API project to the AWS Lambda, the serverless Url not working. Running the project in local is still working, but the serverless Url just wont work. What can possibly be the reason?

[image: Serverless in .NET]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your API is not deployed.

To deploy your API go to the AWS console and try to deploy your API resource:

Use the following options:

**Actions** > **Deploy API**:

[image]

Comment: im new to this aws actually, i have published the asp.net web api project to lambda. so it was supposed to show what the localhost is showing everytime i open up the url.... but it just show the internal server error

Comment: Do you have access to the AWS console?

Comment: yes. I can see that my lambda has already been published

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved the issue. turn out it was my carelessness in the project code. thank you for looking into it. @valdeci